# Why is kdeconnectd, xdg-desktop-portal-kde, and yakuake taking up so much CPU?

Tags: kubuntu, systemd, cpu-load, xdg, kde-connect

[image]

I get this every time on bootup. Killing any of them doesnt work unless I pretty much nuke it from orbit, including uninstalling yakuake.

I am also using Wayland at the moment, and am running Kubuntu 21.04.

What is going on here?